# A pass by ref parameter that is initialized in another function produces invalid conversion error

Tags: c++, parameters, pass-by-reference

```cpp
#include<iostream>

//swap function

void swap(int &x, int &y )
{
    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

//choosing the middle index of the array as the pivot

void choosepivot(int array[],int first,int last) 
{
    swap(array[first],array[(first+last)/2]);
}

//assigns first and last

void firstlastAssign(int array[],int & first, int & last)
{
    first = 0;
    last = sizeof(array)-1;
}

// partitioning function

void partition(int array[], int first, int last, int & pivotIndex)
{   
    firstlastAssign(array,first,last);
    choosepivot(array,first,last);
    int pivot = array[first];
    int lastS1 = first;
    for(int firstUnknown = first+1; firstUnknown<=last; ++firstUnknown)
    {
        if(array[firstUnknown] < pivot)
        {
            ++lastS1;
            swap(array[firstUnknown],array[lastS1]);
        }       
    }
    swap(array[first],array[lastS1]);
    pivotIndex = lastS1;
}

//quicksorting part

void quickSort(int array,int first, int last)
{
    int pivotIndex;
    if(first<last)
    {
        partition(array,first,last,pivotIndex);
        quickSort(array,first,pivotIndex);
        quickSort(array,pivotIndex+1,last);
    }
}

int main(){

    int first,last;

    int ornek[] = {5,87,3,8,0,12,34,6,7,11,73,83,94,92,66};
    quickSort(ornek,first,last);
    int *p;
    p = ornek;
    for(i=0;i<=sizeof(ornek);++i)
    {
        std::cout << p;
        ++*p;   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to be working correctly as I have referenced the original `pivotIndex` value. However, the outcome is producing an error:

> invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

But I don't see where I make a mistake about converting an integer to a pointer, and don't know the debugging method to detect where the problem is.

Comment: `void quickSort(int array,int first, int last)` this function does not accept array inputs

Comment: The error message is telling you that it failed to convert `array` (an int) to the `int[]` expected by `partition`. But why is `array` an `int`? Look at it's definition. `void quickSort(int array, ...` should be `int array[]`. Straightforward reading of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change your quicksort fucntion to accept array instead of integer.

```
void quickSort(int array[], int first, int last)
{
    int pivotIndex;
    if (first < last)
    {
        partition(array, first, last, pivotIndex);
        quickSort(array, first, pivotIndex);
        quickSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, last);
    }
}
```